# Deploy Shopify app on Alma Linux server using cpanel

Tags: node.js, deployment, shopify, cpanel, remix

We are trying to deploy our third party shopify app/plugin on our server. We don't use Heroku nor fly.io.

When installing we get to the point where the app runs on command (npm run start + ENV_VARIABLES) with no error. However we cant seem to be able serve them to our subdomain.

For the rest of our applications we use Python Flask and serve them with Phussion Passenger. Though Passenger should be able to deploy a Node.js app, it doesn't work. This is our Passengerfile.json:

```
{
  "app_type": "node",
  "startup_file": "build/index.js",
  "environment": "production",
  "port": 80,
  "daemonize": true,
   "user": "angelellij"
}
```

We appreciate your help!